# Ionic 4 http.get.subscribe doesn't store value

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, http-get, subscribe

So this is probably a duplicate or something, but I couldn't find anything simple and clear so far, so I'm just gonna ask.

I have some simple code as below:

```
  fetchData() {
    let dataArray: Array<any> = [,,,];
    this.prepareDataRequest()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.dataArray[0] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data["results"]));
      this.dataArray[1] = Object.keys(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data["results"]))).length;
      console.log(this.dataArray[0]);
    },
    err => {
      this.dataArray[2] = `Error --> Status: ${err.status}, Message: ${err.statusText}`;
    });
    return this.dataArray;
  }

  prepareDataRequest() {
    const dataUrl = 'https://randomuser.me/api/?results=10&inc=gender,name,nat,email,phone,id';
    return this.http.get(dataUrl);
  }
```

The `console.log(this.dataArray[0]);` works perfectly, but the return is empty. So far I figured out it's because it executes the `return this.dataArray;` before it has fetched the items.

But how do I fix it? Is there a simple way to say 'wait for everything to be stored before you return'? Or am I doing this completely wrong (probably xD)?

I have tried some things with async and stuff, but I'm kind of new to this so that didn't go all to well.

Comment: You return an empty variable because this is async code. Subscribe() listens to a Observable and it will not executed in the order it is coded. You should read some tutorial and try them until you understand async code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do that in the wrong way, you need to return an observable:

```
fetchData() {
  return this.prepareDataRequest().pipe(
    pluck('results'),
    catchError(err => `Error --> Status: ${err.status}, Message: ${err.statusText}`),
  );
}

someConsumerFunction() {
  fetchData().pipe(
    // do optional processing here
  ).subscribe(
    results => console.log(results),
    err => console.log(err),
  );
}
```

or if you want to wait for completion and use async and a Promise:

```
async fetchData() {
  try {
    const data = await this.prepareDataRequest().pipe(
      first(),
    ).toPromise();

    return data.results;
  } catch (err) {
    return `Error --> Status: ${err.status}, Message: ${err.statusText}`;
  }
}
```

but the first approach is better since you have better flexibility to process your data on the consumer's side.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning your result outside of the subscribe scope, thus the dataArray hasn't been initialised yet.

You need to alter your fetchData() method as such:

```
  fetchData() {
    let dataArray: Array<any> = [, , ,];
    this.prepareDataRequest()
      .subscribe(data => {
          this.dataArray[0] = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data["results"]));
          this.dataArray[1] = Object.keys(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data["results"]))).length;
          console.log(this.dataArray[0]);
          // return your dataArray here
          return this.dataArray;

        },
        err => {
          this.dataArray[2] = `Error --> Status: ${err.status}, Message: ${err.statusText}`;
        });
  }
```

Also, I am a little confused about the declaration of a dataArray local variable while you only use a dataArray field. Perhaps it is not needed there.